# Scikit LogisticRegression cannot learn or,and boolean functions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

It seems the LogisticRegression implemented in scikit-learn cannot learn the simple boolean functions AND or OR. I would understand XOR giving bad results but AND and OR should be fine. Am I doing something wrong?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, LinearRegression
import numpy as np

bool_and = np.array([0., 0., 0., 1.])
bool_or  = np.array([0., 1., 1., 1.])
bool_xor = np.array([0., 1., 1., 0.])


x = np.array([[0., 0.],
              [0., 1.],
              [1., 0.],
              [1., 1.]])

y = bool_and
logit = LogisticRegression()
logit.fit(x,y)

#linear = LinearRegression()
#linear.fit(x, y)

print "expected: ", y
print "predicted:", logit.predict(x)
#print linear.predict(x)
```

gives the following output:

```
expected:  [0 0 0 1]
predicted: [0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: FWIW, I can fit a logit model for `AND` in R without any issues. This suggests the issue is somehow specific to scikits.learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to have to do with regularization. The following makes the classifier work:

```
logit = LogisticRegression(C=100)
```

Unfortunately, the documentation is a bit sparse, so I am not sure what the range of the `C` parameter is.

Comment: Nice finding. Maybe the regularization goes something like 10^(-C)? I'll have to check that. Thanks again.

Comment: The meaning of `C` is the same as in support vector machines (because `LogisticRegression` is a wrapper around LibLinear): its range is (0, ∞) and the higher it's set, the less regularized the model is. I.e., compared to other linear models, C = 1/α. When fitting LR models, *always* do a parameter sweep to find the right setting of C.